# Changing variance based on sigma for a normal distribution

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I am creating an array of random normal distribution for different runs and writing to a `csv` file. I am printing the `mean,var` for each run. I present the current and expected output.

```
from scipy.stats import truncnorm
import numpy as np
import os
import csv 
import pandas as pd
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Runs=5

for i in range(0,Runs): 
    
    mu, sigma = 50.0, 10.0 # mean and standard deviation
    Nodes=220
    r = (1e-6)*np.random.normal(mu, sigma, Nodes)

    sort_r = np.sort(r)
    r1=sort_r[::-1]
    r1=r1.reshape(1,Nodes)
    r2 = r.copy()
    np.random.shuffle(r2.ravel()[1:])
    r2=r2.reshape(1,Nodes)
    maximum = r2.max()
    indice1 = np.where(r2 == maximum)

    r2[indice1] = r2[0][0]
    r2[0][0] = maximum

    r2[0][Nodes-1] = maximum 

    a = (1e-6) * (50 + (r - r.mean()) / r.std())
    mean=a.mean()*1e6
    var=a.std()*1e6
    print("Mean =", mean)
    print("var =", var)
    
    with open(rf"Radius info_{Nodes}ND.txt", 'w+') as f: 

        f.write(f"mean = {str(mean)}\n")
        f.write(f"var = {str(var)}\n")
        #f.write(f"std = {str(std*1e6)}\n")

    r=pd.Series(r*1e6)
    #print("r =",r)
    r.hist()
    plt.xlabel("Pore throat size [\u03BCm]",size=15)
    plt.ylabel("Count",size=15)
    plt.title(rf"var={round(var,1)}",size=25)
    plt.savefig(rf"C:\Users\USER\OneDrive - Technion\Research_Technion\Python_PNM\Surfactant A-D\220 nodes_2\Histogram.png")
    
    
def function(run):
    parent_folder = str(run + 1)
    os.mkdir(parent_folder)

        


        


    with open(os.path.join(parent_folder, rf"Inv_Radius_{Nodes}_{round(mean,1)}_{round(var,1)}ND.csv"), 'w+') as f:
        np.random.shuffle(r2[0][1:-1])
          #print(f'{run}:{r2}')
        inv_r=1/r2
          #print("inv_r =",[inv_r])
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(inv_r)
     


        


        
for x in range(Runs): 
    function(x)
```

The current output is

```
Mean = 49.99999999999999
var = 1.0
Mean = 49.99999999999999
var = 1.0
Mean = 49.99999999999999
var = 0.9999999999999996
Mean = 49.99999999999999
var = 1.0000000000000004
Mean = 49.99999999999999
var = 1.0
```

The expected output is

```
Mean = 49.99999999999999
var = 10.0
Mean = 49.99999999999999
var = 10.0
Mean = 49.99999999999999
var = 0.9999999999999996
Mean = 49.99999999999999
var = 10.0000000000000004
Mean = 49.99999999999999
var = 10.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to divide `r.std()` by sigma (the target std):

Replace:

```
a = (1e-6) * (50 + (r - r.mean()) / r.std())
```

with:

```
a = (1e-6) * (mu + (r - r.mean()) / (r.std() / sigma))
```

Output:

```
Mean = 49.99999999999999
var = 9.999999999999998
Mean = 49.99999999999999
var = 10.0
Mean = 49.99999999999999
var = 10.0
Mean = 49.99999999999999
var = 10.0
Mean = 49.999999999999986
var = 10.0
```

Comment: Right...how can I be sure that the values being written to ```csv``` files have the ```mean=50.0, var=10.0```?

Comment: What do you mean? I don't fully understand what you want to do.